# How can I get the value in a specific column once it selected and passed its value to a Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and show its record in my page, then i put a link in one of the data in column like this. I made the `drawing_part_number` column as link:

my problem is, how can I get the value of the `drawing_part_number` so I will be able to pass it in a query.

Thanks for your help. here is my code.

```
echo "<tr ".$row_color.">";
            echo '<td>' . $row['drawing_type'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['die_type'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['relay_type'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['die_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['part_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['drawing_number'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="show_versions.php">' . $row['drawing_part_number'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['sub_letter'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['specs'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['revision'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<td><a href="show_versions.php?part='.urlencode($row['drawing_part_number']).'">' . $row['drawing_part_number'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: How can I pass the value of the selected drawing_part_number into variable??

Comment: Your `show_versions.php` would receive selected value in GET parameter `part`. You can read that with `$selected_part = $_GET["part"];` in php code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your trying to pass `$row['drawing_part_number']` as a parameter to your `show_versions.php`

Do as follows.

```
echo '<td><a href="show_versions.php?drawing_part_number=' . urlencode($row['drawing_part_number']) . '">' . $row['drawing_part_number'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: how can i pass the value of drawing part number in a variable??

Comment: using `$_GET['drawing_part_number']` in your show_versions.php

Comment: $selected_part = $_GET['part'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT imaster_tbl.id,       imaster_tbl.date,
imaster_tbl.author,
imaster_tbl.die_name,
imaster_tbl.part_name,
irevision_tbl.revision FROM imaster_tbl
        LEFT JOIN irevision_tbl ON imaster_tbl.revision_id = irevision_tbl.revision_id WHERE imaster_tbl.drawing_part_number = '%$selected_part%'")

Comment: thats in my show version code... I tried your idea but I got no result in my query

Comment: `$selected_part = $_GET['drawing_part_number']` not `$_GET['part']`

Comment: I got it already I have error on my SQL command.. Sorry.. anyways thanks a lot for your help..